# Make RecyclerView adapter show different views for different users

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a chat app that uses `Firebase` `firestore` in order to stores chat messages.

There are some specific messages that I want only one of the users to receive.

Currenly I have 2 viewTypes:

1. ViewType for recieved message
2. ViewType for send message

Let say there is the following conversation:

user1 to user2: Hi

user2 to user1: Hey

user1 to user2: `CLICKS ON A BUTTON AND AN AUTOMATIC MESSAGE IS SENT <----want it to show only to user2.`

What will happen now in my adapter is that it will show to both users this message.

How can I make sure that only user2 will get it?

My adapter is:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == AppConstants.CHAT_SENT_KEY) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate(
                R.layout.item_chat_sent,
                parent,
                false );
        return new ChatViewHolder( view );

    } else if (viewType == AppConstants.CHAT_RECEIVED_KEY) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate(
                R.layout.item_chat_received,
                parent,
                false );
        return new ChatViewHolder( view );

    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.item_loading, parent, false );
        return new LoadingViewHolder( view );
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if (viewHolder instanceof ChatViewHolder) {
        ((ChatViewHolder) viewHolder).bind( (chats.get( position )) );
    } else if (viewHolder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
        showLoadingView( (LoadingViewHolder) viewHolder, position );
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (chats.get( position ).getSenderId().contentEquals( userId )) {
        if (position == 0 && chats.size() > 49 && snapSize > 49) {
            return AppConstants.CHAT_LOADING_KEY;
        } else {
            return AppConstants.CHAT_SENT_KEY;
        }
    } else {
        if (position == 0 && chats.size() > 49 && snapSize > 49) {
            return AppConstants.CHAT_LOADING_KEY;
        } else {
            return AppConstants.CHAT_RECEIVED_KEY;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it something connected to `viewTypes` or I should use if conditions in my bind part so only if the id of the user is user2 it will show to him?

Thank you

Comment: You should not do something in the adapter. You pass a list to the adapter to show, right, you can filter this list before passing it to the adapter to show in recycler view. I mean, every row that is shown in recycler view should be corresponding to an item in the list of data. So, the data list for user1 should not contain the specific item.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it something connected to `viewTypes` or I should use if conditions
> in my bind part so only if the id of the user is user2 it will show to
> him?

`viewTypes` is used for showing different layout, usually a layout that is totally different from the other layout.

So, in your case, it is more suitable for you to modify the logic in the `bind` part so it will only show to user2.